# Closed connection or refused connection on port 80

Tags: windows-7-x64, ports

I am having problem with my ports, yesterday I opened port 80 and setup local area connection propeties for ipv4 to use static ip 192.168.1.4, I used ipconifg in cmd to check it first. I am using WAMP server on my pc with windows 7 64-bit. It worked ok.

But today ports are closed, and I didn't changed anything from yesterday. I tried to opened additional ports besides 80 like 8081,443, 8080 in my router with local ip 192.168.1.4 like same setings in my ipv4 propeties to see if give some result, I disabled router firewall, allowed ports to go trough windows firewall, and added all ports for tcp and udp to my norton internet security, I tried also disabling whole firewall but same result.

WAMP is running and listening on port 80, 8081, 8080, 443.

This is part of wamp apache httpd.conf file.

```
 Listen 0.0.0.0:80
    Listen [::0]:80
    Listen 8081
    Listen 443
    Listen 8080


    ServerName localhost:80
```

When I check which program is using port 80, it says Apache/2.4.9  PHP/5.5.12

I noticed that all other ports except 80 and 443 are closed, but 80 and 443 are refusing connection if router firewall is off, and if its on they are closed also. And yesterday I had router firewall on, norton firewall on, and no rules for windows firewall, and it worked.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I think it is off-topic, because it is not about programing. Maybe use ServerFault or Superuser

Comment: I am programing my webserver and ports to run in proper way, I think its a way of programing. I will try both of your sugestion, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the task manager --> processes and close all the process related to apache or JBoss or which ever server you are using. Then try to restart the application. If this does not work try to go the location of the server/ bin folder and run the shutdown.bat in windows or shutdown.sh in linux. It should start working.

Comment: I restarted PC, application, and every other app that may possible be  in connection with web server, I tried turning server offline and online, all with same result. Can you tell me more about shutdown.bat I don't have one in my webserver folder or apache.

Comment: try to find it in the bin folder of the webserver or the installed location of the webserver in program files.

Comment: all apps related to webserver are installed in wamp folder, in root folder I have uninstall_services.bat, also I have buttons on wamp icon to select to restart all services, to turn off, to go offline, and to exit app, I tried all of them. WAMP now wont start

Comment: try to open using the GUI of WAMP and click on the start after changing the port numbers. If it does not work then try reinstalling it.

Comment: I changed several times ports, and all of them I tried, are port forwared to this machine via NAT in router setings. I will try to reinstall.

Comment: Uninstalling did not solved problem, ports still closed.

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot of the error you are facing. it might help me.

Comment: There is no actual error provided by wamp or apache, my problem is closed port at 80, 443, 8080, 8081, and all of them are opened in router, and wamp is listening. Yesterday it worked ok.

Comment: Please follow this. http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/faq/routers/wireless-routers/dkt-series/how-do-i-open-up-ports-to-my-computer-port-forwarding-on-this-router

Comment: This is what I have,
http://puu.sh/csMeo/b5cec31776.png
and like I said in main post, ports are opened by router, I didn't changed anything from yesterday when server worked, I am trying to find out reason why is not working today.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a Web server running on your PC. try to shut it down

Comment: I am having WAMP web server, is combination of apache, php ,mysql, and I want it to run, not to be closed, I just want ports that WAMP is listening on to be opened or not refusing connection.